# ActionBar tittle toggle in DrawerLayout not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawerlayout, navigationview, android-navigationview

I am using [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) with custom side menu (layout) the tittle of the [Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) needs to be changed when drawer is open or when drawer is closed. i have tried to achieve that on onOptionsItemSelected() by toggling the tittle on drawer icon press. but when drawer is swiped open or closed this approach is not working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean isOpen ;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerlayout ;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawerclosed);

   // ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
   // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));



    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.Drawer) ;
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerlayout,R.string.draweropen,R.string.drawerclosed) ;


    mDrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        if(!isOpen)
        {
            isOpen = true ;
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.draweropen);
        }

        else if(isOpen)
        {
            isOpen = false ;
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawerclosed);
        }

           return true ;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Set your title as needed in the `onDrawerClosed()` and `onDrawerOpened()` methods, as shown in the examples on the linked duplicate. Those will run no matter whether the drawer is opened/closed with the toggle button, or by dragging.

Comment: @MikeM. have tried that but app is crashing

Comment: Look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash.

Comment: solved the issue.. !